# Move elements passed into a component using a slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm just starting out with VueJS and I was trying to port over a simple jQuery read more plugin I had.

I've got everything working except I don't know how to get access to the contents of the `slot`. What I would like to do is move some elements  passed into the `slot` to right above the `div.readmore__wrapper`.

Can this be done simply in the template, or am I going to have to do it some other way?

Here's my component so far...

```
<template>
    <div class="readmore">

        <!-- SOME ELEMENTS PASSED TO SLOT TO GO HERE! -->

        <div class="readmore__wrapper" :class="{ 'active': open }">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
        <a href="#!" @click.prevent="toggle" class="readmore__button">Read {{ open ? lessLabel : moreLabel }}</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'read-more',
        data() {
            return {
                open: false,
                moreLabel: 'more',
                lessLabel: 'less'
            };
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                this.open = !this.open;
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use named slots?

Comment: @WaldemarIce - I would have no control of what elements would be passed to the slot, so I can't break them up before I get them to the component. They would be coming out of a CMS. I only said first element to keep the example simple, it could be configurable later on. I've updated the question to make it less focussed on first element.

Comment: @WaldemarIce - Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do what you describe. Manipulating the DOM in a component is typically done in the [`mounted` hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted). If you expect the content of the slot to be updated at some point, you might need to do the same thing in the [`updated` hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated), although in playing with it, simply having some interpolated content change didn't require it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    readMore: {
      template: '#read-more-template',
      data() {
        return {
          open: false,
          moreLabel: 'more',
          lessLabel: 'less'
        };
      },
      methods: {
        toggle() {
          this.open = !this.open;
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        const readmoreEl = this.$el.querySelector('.readmore__wrapper');
        const firstEl = readmoreEl.querySelector('*');
        
        this.$el.insertBefore(firstEl, readmoreEl);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.readmore__wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.readmore__wrapper.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  Hi there.
  <read-more>
    <div>First div inside</div>
    <div>Another div of content</div>
  </read-more>
</div>
<template id="read-more-template">
    <div class="readmore">

        <!-- SOME ELEMENTS PASSED TO SLOT TO GO HERE! -->

        <div class="readmore__wrapper" :class="{ 'active': open }">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
        <a href="#!" @click.prevent="toggle" class="readmore__button">Read {{ open ? lessLabel : moreLabel }}</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thanks a lot. It's the `this.$el` that I was struggling for.